Delphi Indy IdTCPClient ReuseSocket is getting "Socket error # 10048 - Address already in use"
I have this simple code:
var
  IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
  IdTCPClient2: TIdTCPClient;
begin

  IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  IdTCPClient2 := TIdTCPClient.Create;

  IdTCPClient1.UseNagle := False;
  IdTCPClient2.UseNagle := False;

  IdTCPClient1.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
  IdTCPClient2.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;

  IdTCPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1'; // server ip
  IdTCPClient2.Host := '127.0.0.1'; // server ip

  IdTCPClient1.Port := 42000;  // server port
  IdTCPClient2.Port := 42000;  // server port

  IdTCPClient1.BoundIP := '127.0.0.1';
  IdTCPClient2.BoundIP := '127.0.0.1';

  IdTCPClient1.BoundPort := 43000;
  IdTCPClient2.BoundPort := 43000;

  IdTCPClient1.Connect; // connected
  IdTCPClient2.Connect; // get error

but I get the "Address already in use" error, what is wrong?
I've tried different combinations with UseNagle = True too but the result doesn't change

Don't use the same .BoundPort - the whole point of network ports is that each can only be used once client side. Otherwise we wouldn't need ports in addition to the IP address.

I used .BoundPort because I need that all the idTCPClient bound to the same port, they have to share the same port so I'm testing IdTCPClient1.ReuseSocket := rsTrue. Do I miss something?

No, you certainly don't need to. You want to connect to the same server port - that's what .Port is for. But you cannot bind to the same client port - that's what .BindPort is for. You can do that serially, by establishing and closing the first connection and then do the other. You can't do that parallelly. That's a basic principle of IP (Internet Protocol) ports using TCP. Ask someone else with network knowledge.

@AmigoJack "But you cannot bind to the same client port" - yes, you can. Multiple clients can be bound to the same local BoundIP/BoundPort at the same time, but only if they Connect to different server Host/Ports

A TCP connection is uniquely identified by the tuple of its protocol (ie IPv4/IPv6) + source IP/port + destination IP/port.
You cannot have multiple TCP connections active at the same time which have the exact same tuple values. If they did, there would be no way for the OS to differentiate between them. The tuple MUST be unique per TCP connection.
That is why your 2nd Connect() is failing, despite your use of ReuseSocket=rsTrue.  The tuple for the 2nd connection is not unique, it is the exact same as the 1st connection: protocol=IPv4 + source=127.0.0.1:43000 + dest=127.0.0.1:42000.
Multiple clients can be bound to the same local BoundIP/BoundPort at the same time, but only if they Connect() to different server Host/Ports, thus their tuples are unique.

Fully understood Remy, I was trying the socket reuse but I missed that aspect. Tank you
